# Devcon how to automatedly delete drivers using batchfile

Tags: batch-file

here is my devcon command to find all drivers of zte and delete using batchfile

```
@echo off
devcon findall @usb\* |findstr /s /i /c:"usb mass storage" /c:"zte" >zte.txt
For /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%G in (zte.txt) do echo devcon remove "@%%G">>deldriver.bat
deldriver.bat
```

it gives me an error after i run it then devcon not working well after i done this code i cant use the redirect operator to convert it to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it all in a single loop:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%G in ('devcon findall @usb\* ^| findstr /s /i /c:"usb mass storage" /c:"zte"') do (
    devcon remove @%%G
)
```

But the problem might be the quotes in you `echo` statement `"@%%G"`; try removing them

Comment: thanks it works but their is another problem it hit my second usb mass storage device.I want to skip removing the second usb mass storage listed by devcon.I have 2 mass storage device install one is my flashdrive then other one is my data card modem with micro sd card.

Comment: what's the output of devcon `devcon findall @usb\* | findstr /s /i /c:"usb mass storage" /c:"zte"`? so we can filter it down some more

Comment: @user2213859: Please do not try to solve multiple problems in the same thread here. It's perfectly fine to ask for clarifications but when you are asking about a different issue than what you posted originally, please create a new question for it. That way it works best for everyone: for you as the asker, for potential answerers, for people searching for solutions or just browsing answered questions.

Comment: here is the output of usb masstorage in devcon sir USB\VID_0BDA&PID_0159\20071114173400000

Comment: is this the one that you want to remove, or is this one is what you want to keep?  Can I get both of the outputs?